# Playsound giving "command not found: import" message

Tags: python

I am trying to make a piano, and to do that, I wanted to figure out how to make sound first. I have decided on using playsound. I already downloaded it, butI only have this right now:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('/Users/-----/Documents/-------/new sound/low b.wav')
```

I already have an error message saying zsh:command not found: import. I am very bad at coding and would like some help. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is you're trying to run this as a shell command.  For now, you need to run `python xxx.py` to have Python interpret the script instead of shell.

Comment: Or if you are using Python 3 `python3 xxx.py`

Comment: I already enter python3 before dragging the doc.py in. Do i need to do something else?

Comment: As others have pointed out, you should *run the python interpreter , passing doc.py to it, in your zsh terminal* as the previous commenters have shown, using `python doc.py`.

Comment: Basic questions about how to use the terminal are not really suitable for Stack Overflow. We can only infer from the error message that you are running the Python script from `zsh`, but your question doesn't contain enough details to divine what exactly you are doing or what exactly you expect or what exactly you misunderstand. At the Zsh prompt (which out of the box on MacOS looks something like `you@computer directory %`) you can type `python3 doc.py` provided that you have Python 3 installed under that name.

Comment: ... But there are several things here which are subject to speculation and which could be elaborated further if we knew more about where you are coming from.